# Retrieve latest value in a row that is not a specific value in SQL Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, rank

I have a list of users with their accumulated revenue per day and a value is assigned to them.
I would like to see on the latest date what their last change is.

Looking at the example below, their last change was "Yes, Increased to High", on the 9th, but since on the following days, the user didn't increase its revenue, the 'Changed?' column shows "No". I would like to create a column that will tell me what the Latest Change currently is.

Some of the thoughts I've had is maybe using Rank() in some way and omitting the Nos? Ranking the Changed column based on the day? Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this:

```
WITH data_source AS
(
    SELECT User
          ,ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY ROW_NUMBER ORDER BY Date DESC) AS row_id
          ,Changed?
    FROM mytable
    WHERE Changed? LIKE 'Yes%'
)
SELECT mytable.*    
      ,data_source.Changed? AS last_changed
FROM mytable
INNER JOIN data_source
    ON mytable.user = data_source.user
    AND  data_source.row_id = 1
```